# Do you absorb undissolved creatine?

Tags: supplements, creatine

I have MyProtein creatine monohydrate. I don't know if it's just not of a very good quality or if creatine is like this in general, but not much short of boiling water will dissolve it. I've tried putting it in hot drinks but I'm not really a fan of tea and coffee so I was wondering, if I just put it in cold water and kept mixing as I drank it, is the body still able to fully absorb the creatine if undissolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We conclude that creatine administered as meat or in solid form is readily absorbed but may result in slightly lower peak concentrations than when the same dose is ingested as a solution.

[“Absorption of creatine supplied as a drink, in meat or in
solid form”, Harris et. al. *Journal of Sports Sciences*, 2002, 20, 147-151](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gregory-Bogdanis/publication/11547042_Absorption_of_creatine_supplied_as_a_drink_in_meat_or_in_solid_form/links/5517c3cb0cf2f7d80a3baa35/Absorption-of-creatine-supplied-as-a-drink-in-meat-or-in-solid-form.pdf)

You’re fine. It might take you a day or two longer to reach peak muscle saturation, but once you’re there, your maintenance dose will keep you there whether it’s dissolved or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I don't have any studies to back that up, but I personally never put creatine in any kind of fluid.  I stir it in yogurt or cooked oatmeal usually. My bodyweight will decrease significantly when I stop taking it for a week, and then increase right back up once I'm back on. So it's doing *something*.

Comment: Thank you. That yogurt idea is perfect because mixing it with cold water means you have to constantly stir it so it doesn't sink to the bottom.